# How do I write this script in the form of a function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, delay

Alright, so I'm a complete noob at Html and require assistance. I have this piece of Javascript which calls a content locker

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://evodownload.com/content_locker.php?i=4l&s=1&c=0&o=1"></script>`
JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TEHZd/

As you can see, the content locker appears as soon as the page loads, but I'd like it to appear after around 3 minutes. How can I do that?

I came up with this:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript">
function contentlocker(){
**NO CLUE WHAT TO TYPE HERE** <-- THIS IS WHAT I NEED HELP WITH MOSTLY    
}
</script></head>

<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 1800)">
```

But I have no clue what to type as a function to call the locker.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Doing this client side will be very easy to circumvent using DevTools.

Comment: Are you requesting help to install malware on your visitors computers ?

Comment: It's not malware. Never mind the locker itself anyways. I'm here to learn. Clarification:
How can I write this in the form of a function?

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://evodownload.com/topbar.php?p=1&i=4l"></script>

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a string to `setTimeout` it gets evaluated using `eval`. Just pass the function reference instead `setTimeout(delayer, 1800)`

Comment: The problem is OP doesn't know ***what*** to put in the `delayer` function.

Comment: Hint: post title *How do I execute this after a delay?*

Comment: In a nutshell, I need to know how to make this '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://evodownload.com/topbar.php?p=1&i=4l"></script>' a function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've included JQuery...

```
setTimeout(function() {
    doSomething();
}, 1000);
```

where 1000 is 1 second, so replace as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head><script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    delayer();
}, 18000);

function delayer(){
   div = document.getElementById("locker");
   div.style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script></head>

<body>
   <div id ="locker" style="visibility:hidden">
       //PUT/LOAD YOUR LOCKER IN THIS DIV
   </div>
```

Comment: So I simply add 'src="http://evodownload.com/content_locker.php?i=4l&s=1&c=0&o=1' in there?

Comment: it will probably require some slight modifications, like adding script tags, but It should work like this. since everything you put in that div will only appear after the delay.

Comment: I tried '<head><script type="text/javascript">
function delayer(){
   div = document.getElementById("locker");
   div.style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script></head>

<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 1800)">
   <div id ="locker" style="visibility:hidden">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://evodownload.com/content_locker.php?i=4l&s=1&c=0&o=1"></script>
   </div>' but the locker appears instantly, without a delay.

Comment: try increasing the 1800 to 18000, if that doesnt work try my new edited piece. if that doesnt work then I dont know, make sure you dont include it somewhere else by accident.